# Moving a file in processing

Tags: java, file-io, processing

I'm trying to move a file with processing.

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


String source = "C:\test\1.jpeg";
String newdir = "C:\test123\1.jpeg";

void setup() {

Files.move(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName()));


}
```

I took a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) and tried to make it work, however I get an error that The function getFileName() does not exist. I looked for this also, but didn't find much. Could someone point me into the right direction for moving a file from one dir to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

String source = "C:\\test\\1.jpeg";
String newdir = "C:\\test123\\1.jpeg";

void setup() {
    try {
        Path temp = Files.move(Paths.get(source), Paths.get(newdir));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

Couple of points - use `\\` instead of a single `\` when specifying the paths. Secondly, `getFileName()` can only be applied to a Path object, not a String, and that caused your error in the question. Same, by the way, with the `resolve(String s)` method, it can only be applied to a Path, not String.

Using Paths:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

Path source = Paths.get("...");
Path newdir = Paths.get("...");

void setup() {
    try {
        Files.move(source, newdir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```